# PyQGIS - Adding Fields to a Feature Layer

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, features

I'm new to PyQGIS and am having difficulty adding fields to a feature.  I want to plot footprints and assign attributes to each of the footprints.  Here is my script.

```
import csv, ast
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo, QVariant

fileName = 'C:\\directoryname\\temp.csv'
layer = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs=EPSG:4326', 'poly', 'memory')
pr = layer.dataProvider()
attr = pr.addAttributes([QgsField('Object_ID', QVariant.String)])
poly = QgsFeature()
with open(fileName) as f:
    rows = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in rows:
        shape = ast.literal_eval(row['footprint'])
        points = []
        for i in range(0,len(shape['coordinates'][0])):
            points.append(QgsPoint(shape['coordinates'][0][i][0],(shape['coordinates'][0][i][1])))
        poly.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygon([points]))
        poly.setAttribute('Object_ID', row['object_id'])
        pr.addFeatures([poly])
layer.updateExtents()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])
print "Completed!!!"
```

I receive the error

> File "c:/directoryname/tmp9urit7.py", line 19, in
>   
>       poly.setAttribute('Object_ID', row['object_id']) KeyError: 'Object_ID'

When I add the line `caps_string = layer.dataProvider().capabilitiesString()`, then printing caps_string yields that I have full privileges to add, modify, and delete features and attributes.

Also, when I `print attr`, the result is `True`.

If I comment out the line poly.setAttribute('Object_ID', row['object_id']), the script plots the footprints and completes without error, but I have no attributes for any of the footprints.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As out turns out, there were problems in the script.  First, as @artwork21 pointed out, `layer.updateFields()` needed to be added update the fields in the layer.  In addition, the fields also needed to be set in the features within the layer.

```
fields = layer.pendingFields()
poly.setFields(fields, True)
```

Here is the updated script:

```
import csv, ast
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo, QVariant

fileName = 'C:\\directoryname\\temp.csv'
layer = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs=EPSG:4326', 'poly', 'memory')
pr = layer.dataProvider()
attr = pr.addAttributes([QgsField('Object_ID', QVariant.String)])
layer.updateFields()
poly = QgsFeature()
fields = layer.pendingFields()
poly.setFields(fields, True)
with open(fileName) as f:
    rows = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in rows:
        shape = ast.literal_eval(row['footprint'])
        points = []
        for i in range(0,len(shape['coordinates'][0])):
            points.append(QgsPoint(shape['coordinates'][0][i][0],(shape['coordinates'][0][i][1])))
        poly.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygon([points]))
        poly.setAttribute('Object_ID', row['object_id'])
        pr.addFeatures([poly])
layer.updateExtents()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])
print "Completed!!!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not in an edit session you may need to include the updateFields() method after adding the attribute:

> After adding or removing fields in the data provider the layer’s
>   fields need to be updated because the changes are not automatically
>   propagated.

```
pr = layer.dataProvider()
attr = pr.addAttributes([QgsField('Object_ID', QVariant.String)])
layer.updateFields()
#...continue with logic
```

Comment: Your suggestion fixed an issue that I previously did not know I had, but it did not fix the key error issue.  When I print the list of field names, Object_ID is printed.

Comment: Try adding a different field name to the memory layer like "test" and see if that works.  Maybe Object_ID field cannot be created because it is a reserved key word?